# Passing a date range via URL to Civi Form Builder to act as a filter

Tags: formbuilder

using the url

....... #?Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.financial_type_id=108&Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.receive_date=04.04.2023

i can filter a particular form in Form builder for a set Financial Type & date 4.4.2023, is it possible to pass a URL a date range i.e. all of April 2023 (start=01.04.2023&end=30.04.2023, DD/MM/YYYY format), if yes what id the syntax.